# Conda virtual environment not working properly in Anaconda 5.1

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed the latest Anaconda and installed it with default values.

After that, I tried `which python` and it's giving me correct python paths for Anaconda5.1 Python2.7 versions `~/anaconda2/bin`.

Now when I create a virtual environment using the following command:

`conda create -n new_env python=2.7 opencv numpy pandas`

&

`source activate new_env`

When I do `which python` now I get the new virtual environment python `~/anaconda2/envs/new_env/bin/python` which is good. But when I do `which conda` I get the **base anaconda conda** `~/anaconda2/bin/conda` not the **virtual environment conda** path. In previous versions, it wasn't like this.

Am I missing something here?

p.s. I tried with Anaconda5.1 for Python3.6 also, the same result.

Comment: I managed to recreate the issue.  Looks like you are not installing anaconda in the new env.  You could try `onda create -n new_env python=2.7 anaconda` which would solve the problem.  If you activate the source and do `conda list` you will see that anaconda is not installed in the env.

Comment: Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry it didn't but when I tried 
`conda create -n new_env python=2.7 anaconda conda`. That solved the issue of getting proper conda path but if I install packages to this conda it still installs it to the base conda. Looks like both conda are same.

Comment: Anaconda version 4.3.1 is working fine. I'm going ahead with that till I get a solution here.

Comment: This is fully expected. The only conda executable is installed in the base environment. Is there a specific problem that you're having with this?

Comment: I don't think so. Till version 4, whenever you create a virtual env and activate it, the conda it refers to is of that particular virtual env and not for the base conda. In version 5 its base conda always. If you say that this is how it has to be then how can you install environment specific packages from conda?